# C# Expression with Convert and TryCatch

Tags: c#, expression

I need to divide two input double number,and with try catch to handle DivideByZeroException and others.

```
ParameterExpression dInput1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "input1");
ParameterExpression dInput2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "input2");
ParameterExpression e_DBZ = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DivideByZeroException));
ParameterExpression e_ = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Exception));
var _calc = Expression.Divide(dInput1, dInput2);
MethodInfo _consolewrite = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine",new Type[] { typeof(string) });
MethodCallExpression _output = Expression.Call(null, _consolewrite, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(_calc,typeof(double)), typeof(string)));
var _catch_DivideByZeroException = Expression.Catch(e_DBZ, Expression.Call(null, _consolewrite, Expression.Property(e_DBZ, "Message")));
var _catch_Exception = Expression.Catch(e_, Expression.Call(null, _consolewrite, Expression.Property(e_DBZ, "Message")));
var _calc_Block = Expression.Block(_calc, Expression.Constant(0));
var _try = Expression.TryCatch(_calc_Block, _catch_DivideByZeroException, _catch_Exception);
var _lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<double,double, double>>(_try, dInput1,dInput2);
Console.WriteLine(_lambda.Body);
Console.WriteLine(_lambda.Compile().Invoke(1,0));
```

But the Expression.Convert throw System.ArgumentException.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` has many overloads. One of them accepts a `double` so you shouldn't need to `Convert`; call that overload instead. You also don't need the `Expression.Constant(_calc,...)` you can use the result directly: `Expression.Convert(_calc,...)` which makes more sense since `_calc` isn't really a constant

Comment: Your **real** problem is that you can't use `Expression.Constant(_calc, typeof(double))` because the type of that variable is a `BinaryExpression`--**not** `double`; your error comes from Constant and not Convert. See my first comment for how you might get around that. If I wasn't on my phone I'd write you an answer

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yes,it will throw System.InvalidOperationException when I try to use 
Expression.Constant(_calc,...)

Answer (score 0):

You're entire approach doesn't seem right, when you call `Expression.Convert` and outside you issue `Expression.Call()`

But nonetheless, here is a working example of Expression.Convert:

```
// This expression represents a type convertion operation. 
Expression convertExpr = Expression.Convert(
                            Expression.Constant(5.5),
                            typeof(Int16)
                        );

// Print out the expression.
Console.WriteLine(convertExpr.ToString());

// The following statement first creates an expression tree,
// then compiles it, and then executes it.
Console.WriteLine(Expression.Lambda<Func<Int16>>(convertExpr).Compile()());

// This code example produces the following output:
//
// Convert(5.5)
// 5
```

If you dig in into [Expression.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx) doc, you will find a table with the following line:

**Exceptions**

*Exception*:
***ArgumentNullException***

*Condition*:
**expression or type is *null***.

that means that either you're entire expression produces null, or your string is null.

Comment: He gets an argument exception because the type of `_calc` is `BinaryExpression` and not `double`. He's *really* getting the exception in the `Expression.Constant` call, which is nested inside of the `Expression.Convert` making it *seem* like it comes from the latter.

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with this?

```
try
{
  var e_DBZ = dInput1 / dInput2;
}

catch (Exception e)
{
  // Handle Divide by Zero error
  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```